# Issues with outStatistics param of feature layer queries

Tags: javascript, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api, esri-maps

### Problem

When trying to query a hosted feature layer using the `outStatistics` parameter, I get a failed response, whereas spatial queries on the same feature layer return features.

The app is trying to query a feature layer with well data from California. In the CodePen, there are two queries that are made when an address is searched or the buffer radius is modified with the Slider widget:

1. First the outStatistics query that takes multiple fields to query
2. The spatial query based on the buffer geometry.

**CodePen of the app:**

https://codepen.io/dmarkbreiter/pen/abWXRZx

### Troubleshooting

My first guess is that I'm not forming my statistic definitions correctly. However, it appears that they look properly formatted. Below is the code for the statistics query and its associated statistic definition objects:

```
      // Define Statistic Definitions 

      const countActive = {
        onStatisticField: "WellStatus = 'Active'", 
        outStatisticFieldName: "active",
        statisticType: "count"
      };

      const countNew = {
        onStatisticField: "WellStatus = 'New'",
        outStatisticFieldName: "new",
        statisticType: "count"
      };

      const countPlugged = {
        onStatisticField: "WellStatus = 'Plugged'",
        outStatisticFieldName: "plugged",
        statisticType: "count"
      };

      const countIdle = {
        onStatisticField: "WellStatus = 'Idle'",
        outStatisticFieldName: "idle",
        statisticType: "count"
      };

      const countAll = {
        onStatisticField: "WellStatus",
        outStatisticFieldName: "all",
        statisticType: "count"
      };

      
      // Create query object and define outStatistics
      let statsQuery = oilWellsLayer.createQuery();
      statsQuery.outStatistics = [countIdle,
                                 countPlugged,
                                 countAll,
                                 countActive,
                                 countNew];

      // Query feature layer
      oilWellsLayer.queryFeatures(statsQuery).then(response=>{
        console.log(response)
      }).catch(e=>{
        console.log(e);
      })
```

As you can see, with the exception of the `countAll` object, these statistic definitions employ SQL statements in the `outStatisticField` property. They all seem to be valid SQL statements.

My next thought was that perhaps the feature layer, which is owned by an institution that I am not part of, does not allow for statistics to be queried. However, it would appear that the [feature service](https://gis.conservation.ca.gov/server/rest/services/WellSTAR/Wells/MapServer/0) has `Supports Statistics` set to `true`. Perhaps I'm misinterpreting what that means, but I would imagine that would allows for outStatistics.

### Question

**Why is it that I can successfully perform spatial queries on this feature layer but not return outStatistics?** 
Is this a coding issue or an authentification issue?

Answer (score 0):

I could not access the service, but I think you are miss understanding how to do the query. It is actually much more simple.

For what I understand you want to group by `WellStatus`, and then count certain types and all records. In that case I would just use your all condition like this,

```
let statsQuery = oilWellsLayer.createQuery();
statsQuery.groupByFieldsForStatistics = ["WellStatus"];
statsQuery.outStatistics = [{
    onStatisticField: "WellStatus",
    outStatisticFieldName: "well_status",
    statisticType: "count"
}];
```

The result will be all the status and their count, so to obtain the total you need to sum all.

You can always use the where parameter to filter the status, like this,

```
statsQuery.where = "WellStatus IN ('Active','New','Plugged','Iddle')";
```

But in this case you will need another query for the total record number.